# "Subscription validation request failed. Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request"

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I finished this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/azure-functions?tutorial-step=5 everything worked fine until i published my azure Functions in my Azure App.
When i try to make the subscription i get this error "Subscription validation request failed. Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request". When i test with ngrok i can create the subscription with no problems but when i replace NgrokURL value for my Azure function Url, not. Is that the right way to create the susbcription? Also i tried to create the subscription in Graph Explorer but i still get this message.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: check this out for detailed solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75143246/9055645

Answer (score 0):

As the same question raised in MSFT Docs [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/416427/subscription-validation-request-failed-notificatio.html) Forum and thanks to the [Shwetachoudhary](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/3083486/shwetachoudhary-8869.html) provided the solution that helps other community members:

In the following below code,
**content type must be text/plain.

body must include the validation token.**

> 1. [CodeSamples](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample)
>    asp .net mvc sample - Specifically look at the NotificationController.cs file
>    In the method

```
    [HttpPost]  
    public async Task<ActionResult> Listen()  
    {
    if  (Request.QueryString["validationToken"]  !=  null)
    {
    var token =  Request.QueryString["validationToken"];
    return  Content(token,  "plain/text");
    }
```

2. 'notificationUrl' must be able to respond to the request for validation. Make sure the validation token returns as plain/text as well. Refer to the Notification endpoint validation [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation) provided by Microsoft.
3. Try isolating the code and calling the same API with Postman or Graph Explorer and see the results.